# How to auto-import all the controllers in Node Restify application

Tags: node.js, global, require, glob, restify

I have all my controllers in routes folders. So instead of `require(UserController.js)(server)` for each and every new file that I create how can I make glob function that actually works without actually writing require Controller file for every new Controller js file being created!!